# Format txt file

Tags: php, csv

I need to import csv file with php getcsv function but the file is not well formated and cannot import it. After uploading the file, I'd like to delete all " inside the file to have a proper file with ; for each field.

This is an example of my file:

```
"DENO;NAME;SURNAME;""BIRTH"";""ZIP"";CITY;E-MAIL;TELEPHONE"
"M;DAVID;BON;""1959-02-12 00:00:00"";75009;PARIS;email@gmail.com;010000000"
"M;DOE;JHON;""1947-02-02 00:00:00"";75008;PARIS;email@gmail.com;060000000"
"M;DAVE;Philippe;""1950-01-01 00:00:00"";75002;""PARIS"";email@gmail.com;070000000"
```

I think I would need to read each line of the file,and maybe use str_replace but I don't know how to write the new file...

Comment: looks like you could just remove all the quotes and use the semicol to split

Comment: I'm doing that: while (!feof($file_handle)) {
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);} and it's not working, like I just have I column, if I manually delete quotes before importing it's working.

Comment: how are you removing the quotes?

Comment: I tried to edit manually with notepad but It must be done with PHP, so I would like to upload file, save it to disk, then read with php remove all quotes and write file...

Comment: fastest option `sed -i 's/"//g' FILENAME`

Comment: Ok I'll try, I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075144/regex-remove-all-text-within-double-quotes-multiline-included

Comment: don't use `preg_replace` if you going to do it with php `str_replace` is much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get your code into a text string, you can just replace/remove the double-quotes.  Then parse the text and get it into a format that will support fputcsv().

When writing the folder, be sure to check that your user has permissions to write to this folder (for example if the parent folder has permissions **drwxr-xr-x**, you can fix it with **chmod g+w folder_name**).

```
<?php
    // sample text to parse
    $some_text = '"DENO;NAME;SURNAME;""BIRTH"";""ZIP"";CITY;E-MAIL;TELEPHONE"
    "M;DAVID;BON;""1959-02-12 00:00:00"";75009;PARIS;email@gmail.com;010000000"
    "M;DOE;JHON;""1947-02-02 00:00:00"";75008;PARIS;email@gmail.com;060000000"
    "M;DAVE;Philippe;""1950-01-01 00:00:00"";75002;""PARIS"";email@gmail.com;070000000"';

    // remove quotes
    $final_text = str_replace('"', '', $some_text);

    // create array of rows by searching for new lines
    $data = str_getcsv($final_text, "\n");

    // create an empty array to save our final csv data
    $final_csv = array();

    // loop thru the array and save to the final csv data
    foreach ($data as $value) {
            // before saving to final csv data, split row into individual column items 
            $value_array = explode(";", $value);
            $final_csv[] = $value_array;
    }

    // helper debugger to show data before writing it
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($final_csv);
    echo "</pre>";

    // create a new file for writing or open and truncate to 0
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

    // write to file from final csv data
    foreach ($final_csv as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    // close file
    fclose($fp);
?>
```